# Finding the coefficients of the Laurent series

Tags: complex-numbers, laurent-series

Laurent series: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n +\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nz^{-n} $

Questions: Find the coefficients $a_n,b_n$ of the laurent series for the function $f(z)=\frac{2+3z}{z^2+z^4}$ on the annulus $0< |z| < 1$.

Plan: We have a singularity of $z=0$ which is a pole of order $2$. Not really sure how to proceed after identifying the singularity.

Comment: Use the geometric series expansion $1+q+q^2+\dots=1/(1-q)$ for $q=-z^2$, extract that $z^{-2}$ maybe first to have a "Taylor series".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to go is to first note that $$z^2+z^4=z^2\left(z^2+1\right)=z^2(z-i)(z+i),$$ and  that the numerator's degree is less than that of the denominator. Thus, there are constants $a,b,c,d$ such that $$\frac{2+3z}{z^2+z^4}=\frac{a}{z}+\frac{b}{z^2}+\frac{c}{z-i}+\frac{d}{z+i}.$$ I leave it to you to find them. (This is known as a partial fraction decomposition, if you want to look up more about it.)

Next, we could use the fact that for $z\ne 0,$ we have that $$\frac{1}{z+i}=\frac{1}{z}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\left(-\frac{i}{z}\right)}$$ and that $$\frac{1}{z+i}=\frac{1}{i}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\left(-\frac{z}{i}\right)},$$ then use the fact that for $|w|<1,$ we know that $$\frac{1}{1-w}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty w^n.\tag{$\heartsuit$}$$ In order to make $|z|<1,$ it is enough to make $|w|<1$ for one of $w=-\frac{i}{z}$ or $w=-\frac{z}{i}.$ (I'll leave it to you to determine which one.) That will let us rewrite $\frac{d}{z+i}$ as a Laurent series that is valid in the annulus $0<|z|<1,$ and we can similarly rewrite $\frac{c}{z-i}.$ Since $\frac{a}{z}+\frac{b}{z^2}$ is already a Laurent series that's valid in the given annulus, then we can simply add them together, and obtain the series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_nz^{-n}$$ that we wanted. **Note the slight difference between mine and yours. Can you see the reason for it?**

---

The above approach is probably good for you to run through, for practice's sake. However, in this case, we can proceed in an even easier way! Note that $$f(z)=\frac{2+3z}{z^2}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\left(-z^2\right)},$$ and that $0<|z|<1$ if and only if $0<\left|z^2\right|<1,$ so we can use $(\heartsuit)$ to conclude that $$\frac{1}{1-\left(-z^2\right)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(-z^2\right)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nz^{2n}.$$ Hence, $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}\frac{2+3z}{z^2}\cdot(-1)^nz^{2n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(2+3z)z^{2n-2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n2z^{2n-2}+(-1)^n3z^{2n-1}.$$ Can you take it from there to figure out what the sequences $\left\{a_n\right\}_{n=0}^\infty$ and $\left\{b_n\right\}_{n=1}^\infty$ should be?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$ \frac{2+3z}{z^2+z^4} = \frac{2}{z^2}\frac{1}{1+z^2}+ \frac{3}{z}\frac{1}{1+z^2}$$
and $$ \frac{1}{1+z^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n z^{2n} \qquad \text{for } 0<|z|<1$$